# How to pivot rows to columns and column data under the new columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/641f9

[image]

and i would like to select it to look like this

[image]

How it is possible in Sql Server 2008 ?
It is really important to me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Temp
  END
SELECT
  sd.Company,
  sd.Brand,
  'DateFrom' AS Variable,
  sd.DateFrom AS [Date],
  sd.WeekName
INTO
  #temp
FROM
  dbo.SourceData AS sd
UNION ALL
SELECT
  sd.Company,
  sd.Brand,
  'DateTo' AS Variable,
  sd.DateTo AS [Date],
  sd.WeekName
FROM
  dbo.SourceData AS sd

SELECT
  Company,
  Variable,
  Brand,
  NOVW42012,
  MAYW42014,
  AUGW32014,
  APRW12013,
  AUGW52013,
  MARW22014
FROM
  (
   SELECT
    Company,
    Variable,
    Brand,
    [Date],
    WeekName
   FROM
    #temp
  ) sd PIVOT
( MIN(sd.[Date]) FOR WeekName IN (NOVW42012, MAYW42014, AUGW32014, APRW12013,
                                  AUGW52013, MARW22014) ) AS PVT
ORDER BY
  Company,
  Brand
```